# How to generate itextsharp PDF using XML and XSL in C#.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, itext, pdf-conversion

I am looking for code to create a itextsharp pdf file using XML and xslt in an ASP.net application.I was unable find any code from the internet whihc uses xslt transform before converting to pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSLT conversion is unrelated to iTextsharp.  Go find some code that runs XML through an XSLT, and use that.

Then send the resulting XML through the usual XML->PDF conversion process.

Comment: Its css support is spotty at the moment, but is under active development.  The next release will show improvement.